Problem in undestanding how to normalize the input for Xilinx CORDIC Square Root IP
I'm developing a little Verilog module and I'm having trouble understanding how to normalize my data before feeding it into a Xilinx IP that calculates the square root using the CORDIC algorithm. For the normalization, I am basing it on what is done by the Xilinx block shown here (https://docs.amd.com/r/en-US/ug958-vivado-sysgen-ref/CORDIC-SQRT - here I am using the CORDIC IP from the IP catalog).
To give an example, I take the value 1 in Q16.8 format, which in binary would be 0x0100 (1 sign bit, 7 integer bits, and 8 fractional bits). Since the IP accepts an input UFix16.15, I shift it by 7 bits, resulting in 0x8000. However, since the number of shifts is odd, I decrement it by one and then shift the input right by the same quantity. In the end, I get 0x4000, or 0.5 in decimal (UFix 16.15).
At this point, I use CORDIC and get the output value 0x5a82, which is about 0.7071 in UFix 16.15, and that seems correct. Following the instructions in the reported link, for correcting the coordinates I multiply by 2^(-shift), which is a right shift by 3. However, this gives me the result 0xB4E, which in Q16.8 corresponds to just over 11, when I would expect the result to be 1.
The following is the Verilog part I'm am using to normalized the data:
always @(*) begin
    casez (data_in)
        16'b1???????????????: leading_one_position = 15;
        16'b01??????????????: leading_one_position = 14;
        16'b001?????????????: leading_one_position = 13;
        16'b0001????????????: leading_one_position = 12;
        16'b00001???????????: leading_one_position = 11;
        16'b000001??????????: leading_one_position = 10;
        16'b0000001?????????: leading_one_position = 9;
        16'b00000001????????: leading_one_position = 8;
        16'b000000001???????: leading_one_position = 7;
        16'b0000000001??????: leading_one_position = 6;
        16'b00000000001?????: leading_one_position = 5;
        16'b000000000001????: leading_one_position = 4;
        16'b0000000000001???: leading_one_position = 3;
        16'b00000000000001??: leading_one_position = 2;
        16'b000000000000001?: leading_one_position = 1;
        16'b0000000000000001: leading_one_position = 0;
        default:              leading_one_position = 15; //all zeros
    endcase

    shift_count = 15 - leading_one_position;

    x_normalized =  data_in << shift_count;

    if (shift_count % 2 != 0) begin
        x_normalized = x_normalized >> 1;
        shift_count = shift_count - 1;
    end
end

Where am I going wrong?
